# Enthought Canopy: cytpes.util.find_library can't find libc

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, ctypes, enthought

The `shapely` library tries to load functions from libc by finding it with ctypes.util.find_library('c').

In a "normal" Python environment using the Apple-provided system Python, this works:

```
$ python -c 'from ctypes.util import find_library; print find_library("c")'
/usr/lib/libc.dylib
```

But inside the Canopy virtualenv, it fails:

```
$ . /Users/tim/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate
(Canopy 64bit)$ python -c 'from ctypes.util import find_library; print find_library("c")'
None
```

Why? How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Tim, this is a known bug in Canopy, will be fixed in 1.0.3, due out next week.

Comment: Confirmed that this is fixed in Canopy 1.0.3; you will need to restart twice for the fix to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to arise from this logic in ctypes.macholib.dyld.dyld_default_search: https://gist.github.com/tdsmith/5768065

- framework is None for both Pythons
- fallback_library_path is `[]` for system Python and `['/Users/tim/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib', '/Users/tim/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/System/lib', '/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib']` for Enthought
- because fallback_library_path is defined in Canopy, DEFAULT_LIBRARY_FALLBACK (`['/Users/tim/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/lib', '/usr/lib']`) is not examined.

Setting the DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH makes this work:

```
(Canopy 64bit)$ DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib python -c 'from ctypes.util import find_library; print find_library("c")'
/usr/lib/libc.dylib
```

I feel like this is somebody's bug -- maybe ctypes'. (Shouldn't the fallback path only be a fallback?)